# Cake PHP missing controller error new installation

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have installed a new cake installation on my apache server. At first I was receiving errors about rewrite. I followed all of the instructions at cakephp.org and I now get the initial page to work when I go to the url:
    localhost/username/cake/app/webroot/index.php

Which give me the basic status of my installation everything checks out.

However when I attempt to go to local/host/username/cake I get an error saying I am missing Error: usernameController could not be found
Error: Create the class usernameController below in file…

I believe there is a mod-rewrite error or https.config I am not seeing because if I type anything else into the url like localhost/username + '4'/cake/ I get the following error

Error: username4Controller could not be found…

I have the cake setup in my Sites folder on my Mac, I have all three .htaccess files in their correct locations in the cake setup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: yes, I uncommented it in my httpd.conf, is there anyway to check its working?

Comment: I would assume it's not working.  The problem you're describing very much sounds like it's not.